# Magento 2: Error updating to 2.1.8 and 2.1.9

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-2.1.8

After updating to 2.1.8, and more recently trying 2.1.9, my category pages stopped displaying products.

I started seeing an error when reindexing:

> There is no such adapter: mysql2

I put my dev site into developer mode to get more info. When opening a category page I see the above error and this one as well:

> Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`entity_id` NOT IN ('4336', '4337', '4338', '4341', '4336', '4337', '4338', '43' at line 4, query was:
>
> INSERT INTO `search_tmp_59c45499257c35_41892677` SELECT `main_select`.`entity_id`, MAX(score) AS `relevance` FROM (SELECT `search_index`.`entity_id`, (((0) + (0)) * 1) AS `score` FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1` AS `search_index`
>    LEFT JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `cea` ON search_index.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `category_ids_index` ON search_index.entity_id = category_ids_index.product_id
>    LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_index` ON search_index.entity_id = stock_index.product_id AND stock_index.website_id = 0 WHERE (stock_index.stock_status = 1) AND (category_ids_index.category_id = 14) AND (`search_index`.`entity_id_filter`.`search_index`.`entity_id` NOT IN ('4336', '4337', '4338', '4341', '4336', '4337', '4338', '4341'))) AS `main_select` GROUP BY `entity_id` ORDER BY `relevance` DESC
>    LIMIT 10000

I tried changing the database entries in my `core_config_data` data table where path is `search/engine/engine`/ and `catalog/search/engine` from `mysql2` to `mysql`.

After recompile removed the "no such adapter" error, but the second error is still there. In retrospect, this doesn't seem right because I've since checked the live database of my site and both entries are `mysql2`.

So I have a few questions with this, but the obvious and most important one is **how can I fix this error**?

Not as important but I'm also curious what the difference between `mysql` and `mysql2` in the option. How do I know what option to use in the future?

Comment: This probably won't help anyone but I narrowed it down to a specific module.

Answer (score 0):

TL DR

Restore your SQL database  from the backup that was created before the update.

SSH in your server and run

`php bin/magento setup:rollback -d sqlbackupFileName`

Find the SQL back file name with 
`php bin/magento info:backups:list`